# Controllers in Play framework

Tags: java, eclipse, model-view-controller, playframework-1.x

I'm new to play framework. I can't get the idea of the controllers package. how can i use them and what are they for? 
if I have a clickable button, how can I link it to the action I want?? please, Need an answer! Thank You

Comment: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/controllers

Comment: Adn plz add, the version of play framework. Even though this is general question.

Answer (score 0):

Controller in Play Framework is common MVC controller: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

As Olivier mentioned in his comment you can read about in official documentation of Play how does it works.

There's also [routing mechanism](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/routes) in Play Framework which 'translates' your request to controller.action(params) set.

Nevertheless of all of this I would suggest you to start with version 2.0 of Play. It Has Java support too and has also some sample applications which will allow you to get idea of Play's MVC just faster.

Answer (score 0):

action for links:

```
<a href="@{ControllerName.methodView(argName)}">${phone}</a>
```

and forms:

```
<form action="@{ControllerName.methodSave()}" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```